# web page to read client side registry

Tags: javascript, html

I currently have a web app that uses ActiveX / JScript to read files and to read the registry for a web page. Originally when designing the page, it was supposed to be on a site that only supported IE...then things changed and it is no longer that way. My question:

HTML5 is able to read files. Is there any way to read registry entries outside of ActiveX and internet explorer using javascript/html? I'm trying to avoid having to port the entire applet over to use Java, but that may be my best method.

The page makes no modifications, it only reads text files and registry entries.

Comment: Instead of the settings being saved in the registry, can they be stored on the server instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not possible without a third party plugin.

Comment: That's somewhat unfortunate, but I was pretty sure that was the case anyways. Thanks.

Comment: No problem, while this puts a damper on your development, just consider the security implications if browsers could directly access users registry. I hope you find a solution

Comment: I'm still a little torn on this subject. On one hand, it'd be very convenient if I could do this without using third party applications. On the other hand, it does pose a very significant risk to your computer if any web page you click "yes" on can read/modify your registry.